# c# port - multiple video/voice lines

Tags: c#

If I have one activated port (let's say 5060) and i want to add 2 communication lines (like in a video conference) what is the easiest way to do it? I would like some examples.

Comment: Can be useful? http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Video_Voice_Conferencing.aspx?display=Print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with a tcplistener?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx

Comment: thx. Can you give me some ideas for multiple imbpund calls to a single sip number? Is the server responsable fot his?

Comment: I have no actual knowledge on how the SIP protocol works on top of TCP/IP. But form reading the first few chapters of the SIP RFC http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3261.txt learns that the protocol works similar to http so, request-respone. So having the listener handoff the incoming request to a thread will allow you to handle more than one connection. Maybe peek into the source code of some open source stuff to lesarn: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SIP_software